# How to grant a user access for specific time?

Tags: symfony, acl, roles

I am building a website users have to pay for different functions. For example the user have payed for "packet 1" for the current month and it includes "short messages". How can I check, if a user is allowed to send sms? Updating the user/role relations every night or is there anything more dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You could add custom voter, where you can check if a user is allowed to use certain service. See example here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Comment: Voters are a good idea. I must see how to use it in my context, because not everything I need to controll is a own entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table in a database which has a foreign key to a table of which contains different packages, a foreign key to your user table and finally a column which indicates the expire date of the package.

If the package is not found for that user and for that expire date then the user is not allowed to send sms.

You can use some other storage procedures but using a database makes most sense.

Basically: You don't want to update anything, you simply want to store certain information like the expire date (and maybe the starting date if you want to change the expire duration) and compare to that selected value.

Comment: Yeah, thats easy. The question is about how to use it in a symfony2 security context like "->isGrant('send_sms')"... I'll take a look on security voters.